# select variable letter index from file

Tags: bash, sed

Say I have a file

```
3 boy
2 hello
3 bus
```

and I want to select the `i`th letter from each line, where i is the number in front of the line (resulting in `y`, `e`, `s`). Is there an easy way to do this with `sed`/`cut`? I tried matching for example the substring with the first that many letters with

```
cat test.txt | sed -e 's/\([0-9]\) \(.*\)\{\1\}.*/\2/'
```

to then cut it afterwards, but this yields an error `Invalid content of \{\}`. What is the proper way to do this (preferrably with just sed/cut/... so without for-loops etc.)?

I am looking for a way that can be done as pipelining, i.e. starting the line with `cat test.txt | ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a single `awk` script can be written as

```
awk '{print substr($2,$1,1)}' inputFile
```

gives output as

```
y
e
s
```

`substr(str, pos, len)` function returns the substring starting at postion `pos` with length as `len`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop:

```
while read -r number name
do
   echo "${name:$number - 1:1}"
done < file
```

This takes profit of the `${string:position:length}` syntax: extract `$length` characters substring from `$string` at `$position`. As the first character is at position `0`, we have to substract 1 to get the needed one.

For your given input it returns:

```
$ while read -r number name; do echo "${name:$number - 1:1}"; done < a
y
e
s
```